# Add PDF resources C # english - french

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a project to print a bill in pdf in which I want to take the details of the imprission (name, first name, address ...) by using the resources that I initialized in the files in french and in english (`Resources.en-US.resx`, `Resources.fr-FR.resx`).

When I click in the French checkbox the information changes in French and the same in English.

My code is the following :

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

if (langue == LangueAgence.FR)
{
    cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);                                                
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.LINK_Nom_agence.ToUpper(), 239, 817, new BaseColor (49, 140, 231), 12, true,0);
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.Link_Nom.ToUpper(), 112, 700, BaseColor.WHITE, 10, false);//First name
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.Link_Prenom.ToUpper(), 112, 682, BaseColor.WHITE, 10, false);//last name  }
} 
else if (langue == LangueAgence.EN)
{
    cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.LINK_Nom_agence.ToUpper(), 239, 817, new BaseColor(49, 140, 231), 12, true, 0);
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.Link_Nom.ToUpper(), 112, 700, BaseColor.WHITE, 10, false);//First name
    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.Link_Prenom.ToUpper(), 112, 682, BaseColor.WHITE, 10, false);//last name
}
```

I would like to have a code that allows me to receive details in English or French as appropriate in the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and that's it

```
if(langue == LangueAgence.FR)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"); 
                }
                else if(langue == LangueAgence.EN)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                }                        

                    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.LINK_Nom_agence.ToUpper(), 239, 817, new BaseColor (49, 140, 231), 12, true,0);
                    AddElement.AddTextAgencyFB(ref cb, Properties.Resources.Link_Nom.ToUpper(), 112, 700, BaseColor.WHITE, 10, false);//Last name
 }
```

the problem is solved